# Como obter uma linha aleatória em uma tabela grande?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma tabela com mais de 780 mil registros e preciso obter uma linha aleatória dessa tabela. Eu consigo fazer isso com:

```php
$randomRow = Table::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Acontece que, essa consulta leva bastante tempo para ser executada pela razão da imensidão da tabela. Eu preciso de uma solução mais rápida e dinâmica, mas não encontro como fazer isso.

Também notei que há um consumo grande de memória nessa consulta, e não posso colocar isso em produção ou o servidor ficará congestionado rapidamente.

A tabela não há chave primária, mas contém uma coluna chamada `NUM` que é única e pode ser utilizada como ID. Ela não é sequencial, mas tem tamanho fixo de 11 dígitos.

Como posso fazer uma consulta rápida para obter uma linha aleatória em uma tabela?

> Estou utilizando Laravel 9.2 com PHP 8.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250141/4698166) me deu uma luz de como fazer isso:

```php
$r = rand(0, 99999999999);
$randomRow = Pessoa::where('NUM', '>=', $r)->first();
```

Isso diminuiu consideravelmente o tempo de resposta. Pelo que entendi, a consulta era lenta porque a função `ORDER BY RAND()` do MySQL dedicava um valor aleatório a todas os registros e escolhia o menor deles. Como a tabela é enorme, ele tinha que associar um valor aleatório para todos os registros da tabela.

A função acima compara se a coluna `NUM` é maior que o pseudo-aleatório `$r` e limita a busca para 1 registro, obtendo um valor aleatório.